# Div elements do not stretch when they do not fit text (min-height used)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm trying to make a chat but now I'm facing a problem *Div elements do not stretch when they do not fit text (min-height used)*. By **div elements** I mean the messages of the chat:
[image: Message example] (when you hover on a message, it changes its background to a darker color and there you can see that it has padidng)

As you can see, they have padding (they also stretch when they have more text) but here is a problem. Stretching and changing their height when they have more text is not problematic with **only 1 message**. But after adding new divs (messages), the message padding somewhy starts disappearing. Here is an example, [image: 3 messages exapmle] (technically they have no padding)

Here is the codepen (I make that on my computer but I've temporary moved file contents to codepen.io so some images won't be visible): https://codepen.io/dubbler/pen/dyWvVEP

(to people who don't want to go on codepen.io)

***chat.php edit="(only html content yet)"***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat - Uranus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


    <meta name="keywords" content="uranus, social, media, uranus social media, uranium, chatting, talking">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Uranus">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Uranus - New way of Chatting">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Want to have fun with the other people? You are here! Uranus is a new social media that is keeps everything anonymous.">
    <meta property="og:url" content="uranus.com">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
    <meta property="og:image" content="favicon.ico">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__item header__logo-container">
        <img id="header-logo" src="favicon.ico" alt="Uranus Logo">
        <h1 id="header-title">Uranus</h1>
    </div>

    <nav class="header__item nav">
        <a class="nav__links" href="#">My Account</a>
        <a class="nav__links" href="#">Feed</a>
        <a class="nav__links" href="#">Messages</a>
        <a class="nav__links" href="#">Friends</a>
    </nav>
</header> <!-- /.header -->

<div class="main">
    <div class="chats">
        <a class="chats__chat selected" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat selected">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="chats__chat" href="">
            <div class="chats__chat">
                <img class="chats__avatar" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s avatar picture">
                <div class="chats__recent_info">
                    <p class="chats__username">Alex Dubbler</p>
                    <p class="chats__last_message">Last Message lorem ipsum dolor, sit<br> amet idk what im writing but ok yes i...</p>
                    <!-- .chat__last_message => ... after 70 symbols; <br> after 35 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
        

    <div class="chat_section">
        <div class="chat">
            <div class="chat_inner">
                <div class="chat-message chat-message-ID">
                    <img class="message-userpfp" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s Avatar">
                    <div class="chat_message_info">
                        <p class="sender_name">Alex_Dubbler</p>
                        <p class="message_text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, quaerat facere fugit, debitis molestiae corrupti totam dicta repellat fuga nostrum nemo, labore quod deleniti officia voluptatibus. Eum reprehenderit tempore quo alias perspiciatis ipsa molestias consequuntur non exercitationem! Fugit voluptas expedita neque culpa molestiae iusto, natus ipsa ipsum ducimus hic unde illum aliquam! Ad rem unde reprehenderit! Nam ad ducimus facere provident debitis qui necessitatibus atque architecto aliquam, a quaerat tenetur deleniti. Laboriosam qui sunt, dolorum natus eveniet reprehenderit recusandae nobis eligendi, distinctio excepturi non. Consectetur ad laborum vel sed totam error optio accusamus, unde libero explicabo nulla quam qui, vero officiis quis labore rerum harum sapiente. Delectus eum tempore natus quos corrupti accusamus, aspernatur praesentium ex laborum veritatis, commodi possimus cum fuga unde sed nostrum vel veniam error doloremque eveniet? Amet, voluptatibus ad optio quasi maxime dignissimos fuga, nam aliquam vel autem pariatur! Natus assumenda, unde sint placeat dicta fugiat eveniet mollitia recusandae accusamus esse, nostrum repellat laboriosam modi eius, voluptate magnam repellendus at eaque exercitationem ab! Deleniti libero, dignissimos voluptatum ex repudiandae dolorum tenetur laboriosam, ratione totam illum ullam quasi aspernatur. Sit nesciunt sint voluptatibus molestias aliquam ipsam laudantium ut debitis tempora odio. Ex quaerat necessitatibus sit dolore excepturi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-message chat-message-ID">
                    <img class="message-userpfp" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s Avatar">
                    <div class="chat_message_info">
                        <p class="sender_name">Alex_Dubbler</p>
                        <p class="message_text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, quaerat facere fugit, debitis molestiae corrupti totam dicta repellat fuga nostrum nemo, labore quod deleniti officia voluptatibus. Eum reprehenderit tempore quo alias perspiciatis ipsa molestias consequuntur non exercitationem! Fugit voluptas expedita neque culpa molestiae iusto, natus ipsa ipsum ducimus hic unde illum aliquam! Ad rem unde reprehenderit! Nam ad ducimus facere provident debitis qui necessitatibus atque architecto aliquam, a quaerat tenetur deleniti. Laboriosam qui sunt, dolorum natus eveniet reprehenderit recusandae nobis eligendi, distinctio excepturi non. Consectetur ad laborum vel sed totam error optio accusamus, unde libero explicabo nulla quam qui, vero officiis quis labore rerum harum sapiente. Delectus eum tempore natus quos corrupti accusamus, aspernatur praesentium ex laborum veritatis, commodi possimus cum fuga unde sed nostrum vel veniam error doloremque eveniet? Amet, voluptatibus ad optio quasi maxime dignissimos fuga, nam aliquam vel autem pariatur! Natus assumenda, unde sint placeat dicta fugiat eveniet mollitia recusandae accusamus esse, nostrum repellat laboriosam modi eius, voluptate magnam repellendus at eaque exercitationem ab! Deleniti libero, dignissimos voluptatum ex repudiandae dolorum tenetur laboriosam, ratione totam illum ullam quasi aspernatur. Sit nesciunt sint voluptatibus molestias aliquam ipsam laudantium ut debitis tempora odio. Ex quaerat necessitatibus sit dolore excepturi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-message chat-message-ID">
                    <img class="message-userpfp" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s Avatar">
                    <div class="chat_message_info">
                        <p class="sender_name">Alex_Dubbler</p>
                        <p class="message_text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, quaerat facere fugit, debitis molestiae corrupti totam dicta repellat fuga nostrum nemo, labore quod deleniti officia voluptatibus. Eum reprehenderit tempore quo alias perspiciatis ipsa molestias consequuntur non exercitationem! Fugit voluptas expedita neque culpa molestiae iusto, natus ipsa ipsum ducimus hic unde illum aliquam! Ad rem unde reprehenderit! Nam ad ducimus facere provident debitis qui necessitatibus atque architecto aliquam, a quaerat tenetur deleniti. Laboriosam qui sunt, dolorum natus eveniet reprehenderit recusandae nobis eligendi, distinctio excepturi non. Consectetur ad laborum vel sed totam error optio accusamus, unde libero explicabo nulla quam qui, vero officiis quis labore rerum harum sapiente. Delectus eum tempore natus quos corrupti accusamus, aspernatur praesentium ex laborum veritatis, commodi possimus cum fuga unde sed nostrum vel veniam error doloremque eveniet? Amet, voluptatibus ad optio quasi maxime dignissimos fuga, nam aliquam vel autem pariatur! Natus assumenda, unde sint placeat dicta fugiat eveniet mollitia recusandae accusamus esse, nostrum repellat laboriosam modi eius, voluptate magnam repellendus at eaque exercitationem ab! Deleniti libero, dignissimos voluptatum ex repudiandae dolorum tenetur laboriosam, ratione totam illum ullam quasi aspernatur. Sit nesciunt sint voluptatibus molestias aliquam ipsam laudantium ut debitis tempora odio. Ex quaerat necessitatibus sit dolore excepturi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-message chat-message-ID">
                    <img class="message-userpfp" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s Avatar">
                    <div class="chat_message_info">
                        <p class="sender_name">Alex_Dubbler</p>
                        <p class="message_text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, quaerat facere fugit, debitis molestiae corrupti totam dicta repellat fuga nostrum nemo, labore quod deleniti officia voluptatibus. Eum reprehenderit tempore quo alias perspiciatis ipsa molestias consequuntur non exercitationem! Fugit voluptas expedita neque culpa molestiae iusto, natus ipsa ipsum ducimus hic unde illum aliquam! Ad rem unde reprehenderit! Nam ad ducimus facere provident debitis qui necessitatibus atque architecto aliquam, a quaerat tenetur deleniti. Laboriosam qui sunt, dolorum natus eveniet reprehenderit recusandae nobis eligendi, distinctio excepturi non. Consectetur ad laborum vel sed totam error optio accusamus, unde libero explicabo nulla quam qui, vero officiis quis labore rerum harum sapiente. Delectus eum tempore natus quos corrupti accusamus, aspernatur praesentium ex laborum veritatis, commodi possimus cum fuga unde sed nostrum vel veniam error doloremque eveniet? Amet, voluptatibus ad optio quasi maxime dignissimos fuga, nam aliquam vel autem pariatur! Natus assumenda, unde sint placeat dicta fugiat eveniet mollitia recusandae accusamus esse, nostrum repellat laboriosam modi eius, voluptate magnam repellendus at eaque exercitationem ab! Deleniti libero, dignissimos voluptatum ex repudiandae dolorum tenetur laboriosam, ratione totam illum ullam quasi aspernatur. Sit nesciunt sint voluptatibus molestias aliquam ipsam laudantium ut debitis tempora odio. Ex quaerat necessitatibus sit dolore excepturi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-message chat-message-ID">
                    <img class="message-userpfp" src="img/AVdubbler.png" alt="<user>'s Avatar">
                    <div class="chat_message_info">
                        <p class="sender_name">Alex_Dubbler</p>
                        <p class="message_text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, quaerat facere fugit, debitis molestiae corrupti totam dicta repellat fuga nostrum nemo, labore quod deleniti officia voluptatibus. Eum reprehenderit tempore quo alias perspiciatis ipsa molestias consequuntur non exercitationem! Fugit voluptas expedita neque culpa molestiae iusto, natus ipsa ipsum ducimus hic unde illum aliquam! Ad rem unde reprehenderit! Nam ad ducimus facere provident debitis qui necessitatibus atque architecto aliquam, a quaerat tenetur deleniti. Laboriosam qui sunt, dolorum natus eveniet reprehenderit recusandae nobis eligendi, distinctio excepturi non. Consectetur ad laborum vel sed totam error optio accusamus, unde libero explicabo nulla quam qui, vero officiis quis labore rerum harum sapiente. Delectus eum tempore natus quos corrupti accusamus, aspernatur praesentium ex laborum veritatis, commodi possimus cum fuga unde sed nostrum vel veniam error doloremque eveniet? Amet, voluptatibus ad optio quasi maxime dignissimos fuga, nam aliquam vel autem pariatur! Natus assumenda, unde sint placeat dicta fugiat eveniet mollitia recusandae accusamus esse, nostrum repellat laboriosam modi eius, voluptate magnam repellendus at eaque exercitationem ab! Deleniti libero, dignissimos voluptatum ex repudiandae dolorum tenetur laboriosam, ratione totam illum ullam quasi aspernatur. Sit nesciunt sint voluptatibus molestias aliquam ipsam laudantium ut debitis tempora odio. Ex quaerat necessitatibus sit dolore excepturi.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
                        

        </div>
        
        <form class="messagebox">
            <button id="send_message"><img src="img/send_img.svg"></button>
            <input id="messagebox-input" placeholder="Write a message..." type="text">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***style.css***

```
/* Variables
================== */

:root {
    --logoTextColor: #1c1c1c;
    --whiteGrey: #d9e0e2;
}


/* Fonts
=================== */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('fonts/Myriad Pro Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}


/* Fonts End
=================== */

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
body {
    color: var(--whiteGrey);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* body > * {
    height: 100%;
} */

*,*::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* Header
================ */

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    /* min-height: 137px; */
    min-height: 12.6815%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #436793;
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #000;
}
.header > * {
    width: 100%;
}


.header__logo-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 440px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-right: 85px;
}
#header-logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#header-title {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1c1c1c;
    font-size: 9rem;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav__links {   
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--whiteGrey);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;

    transition: all .2s linear;
}
.nav__links:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Main
============== */

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 87.3185%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Chats */

.chats {
    min-width: 439px;
    min-height: 127px;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #798594;
}

.chats::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
.chats::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #c8c7c7;
}
.chats::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #666;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* border-radius: 50px; */
}
  
/* Handle on hover */
.chats::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #333;
} 

.chats__chat {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #798594;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.chats__chat.selected {
    background-color: #555d68;
}
a.chats__chat {
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
div.chats__chat {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.chats__avatar {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
}
.chats__recent_info {
    text-align: left;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.chats__username {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--whiteGrey);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.chats__last_message {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--whiteGrey);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.chats__chat:hover * {transition: color .25s linear;transition: background-color .1s linear;}
div.chats__chat:hover:not(.selected) {background-color: #626c77 !important;}
a.chats__chat:hover * {
    color: #fff;
}


/* Chat
=============== */

.chat_section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #707a87;

    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
}

.messagebox {
    background-color: #434b54;
    height: 11.12266vh;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.messagebox > button[id="send_message"] > img {
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
}

#send_message {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.messagebox > input[type="text"] {
    width: 90%;
    height: calc(100% - 2rem);
    margin: auto 0;
    border-radius: 36px;
    border: 0.5rem solid #436793;
    background-color: #707a87;
}
.messagebox > input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: var(--logoTextColor);

    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-3%, -50%);
}
.messagebox > input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: var(--logoTextColor);

    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-3%, -50%);
}

.chat {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background-color: #707a87;
    min-height: 88.87734%;

    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.chat_inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background-color: #707a87;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;

    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* .chat > div {
    flex: 1;
} */
.chat_inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1rem;
}
.chat_inner::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #c8c7c7;
}
.chat_inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #666;
    border: 0.1rem solid #000;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    /* border-radius: 50px; */
}
  
/* Handle on hover */
.chat_inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #333;
} 







.chat-message {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 5rem;

    padding: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.chat-message:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.chat-message:hover, .chat-message.selected {
    background-color: #5f6772;
}




.message-userpfp {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    align-self: flex-start;
}



.chat_message_info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.sender_name {
    justify-self: flex-start;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    word-break: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 1.8rem;
    min-height: 1.8rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.message_text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    word-break: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Get rid of height: 100% for html and body in your CSS

Comment: @CharanKumar it worked, now everything is okay in chats but not with the .main div. Now body is not 100% height but now scrollable. I've put max-height: 100% !important; on body but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The quick fix**

You have put a `display: flex` on both the `.chat` and it's `.chat_inner` child while it's only needed on the `.chat_inner`, here is a [working version](https://codepen.io/pvds/pen/bfa7e10e471975c759145f597b77d794)

### Some tips

The issue you encounter is part of a more fundemental problem.
I see quite a number of (potential) bugs and suboptimal/redundant HTML structures and CSS styling which make your code less readable, scalable and maintainable.

- **find a structured way of implementing designs into code**
  What works for me is developing the HTML/CSS for reusable components and page layout separately
- **provide a reduced use case**;
  This can help you debug the problem on your own, if you can't figure it out on your own it's easier to provide a solution
- **gain a deeper understanding of HTML/CSS concepts, methodologies and properties** for CSS layout I recommend [Rachel Andrew's The CSS workshop](https://thecssworkshop.com/) and in general the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is an amazing resource
- **avoid changing the visual order** (eg. by using `flex-direction: column-reverse`)
  It's better to render HTML in the correct order (to keep your code clean and improve accessibility).